# How to use different Matrices inside a loop in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a for loop in Matlab; inside it I am calling a function which uses a matrix as an input. Here is how it looks:

```
for S=1:10
...
functionA(optimumS1)
...
end
```

I loaded optimumS1, optimumS2... matrices. How can I use different matrices each time?

Comment: What do you mean by "each time"? Do you mean in every iteration? If S=1 use optimumS1, if S=2 use optimumS2 and so on...?

Comment: @Niclas Yes Niclas.I was trying do this:filename = ['OptimumS' num2str(S)]; But I need to convert char to variable since file name is a char

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using a cell array:

```
optimum = {optimumS1, optimumS2, ..., optimumS10 };
for S=1:length(optimum)
    ...
    functionA(optimum{S});
    ...
end
```